# Write a SQL query to print words that do not contain '%' symbol in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE ('%%%');
```

Assume that the table has only one column. The problem is that the query doesn't recogonize the % inside *NOTLIKE* as a character, rather as a part of the syntax itself. How do I rectify this?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE !LOCATE('%', columnname);`

Comment: I was thinking of replacing the `%` with something else then use that in the condition but I like @Akina answer better!

Comment: In general - never use LIKE when you need to test for definite literal. It is designed for patterns only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the option of [escaping characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE '%\%%';
```

Or:

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE '%|%%' ESCAPE '|';
```

Comment: This worked just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can use []

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE ('%[%]%');
```

Comment: good to you, perfect!

Comment: May I know which MySQL version can do this?

Comment: it used in sql server,in mysql i don't know

Comment: mysql does not support this

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had in mind:

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE REPLACE(COLUMNNAME,'%','findthis') NOT LIKE ('%findthis%');
```

By replacing the symbol with something else then use it as the condition in `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: `'findthis'` may occur in the value. The literal which is absent in the value with guarantee must be used. I prefer `CHAR(0)`...

Comment: I take note of that @Akina. Thanks!